# Dell Optiplex 745 crashes with SSD

Tags: ssd, sata

I replaced the HDD with an SSD on my Dell Optiplex 745.

Every 3 hours or so (it seems), the PC crashes, and reboots, and during reboot, it says there is no SATA device found.

If I press CTRL+ALT+Del, I get the same message, but if I shut down, and power back up, the SSD is detected, and Windows will boot.

There is nothing in the event viewer. This only started happening after I changed to an SSD.

The SSD is a [Samsung 850 EVO 250GB](http://www.austin.net.au/samsung-850-evo-250gb-internal-solid-state-dr.html).

Comment: Can you describe the crash? Do you get a blue screen? If so, what's the stop code?

Comment: Change the settings in the bios to AHCI.

Comment: Also try updating the SSDs Firmware.

Comment: One possibility is you have a defective ssd drive.